# Webpack server loop disconnect reconnect angular 15

Tags: angular, webpack

Hello i have an issue in localhost with Devpack server in Angular 14/15.
Refreshing changes made in a controller causes a long wait before refreshing the page. Checking the console for an explanation, I saw that the server tries to connect and disconnects multiple times before establishing the connection.

I also encountered this problem on a new project with only one page and some images. There is no logic, http call or anything else that could interfere. What do you think it is due to? Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem of console throwing never-ending loop of notices.

> [webpack-dev-server] Disconnected
> [webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect...

Not an expert, so I'm not sure if this kind of issue actually resides in the app or packages side because after I troubleshoot on my own, the solution I found was to:

**Add 'localhost' to Trusted URLs** in Kaspersky's Safe Browsing settings.
For different antivirus, this should be around the web/network protection settings.

Comment: This indeed fixes the disconnect issue! Thanks a lot